# Is "conquer fear" the same as "facing fear" in this example

Tags: meaning, dialogue

The following dialogue is from the movie **Batman Begins**:

Ra's Al Gul to Bruce Wayne

> To conquer fear, you must become fear. You must bask in the fear of
>   other men.

So when Ra's Al Gul asks Bruce Wayne to "become fear" is he suggesting that Wayne must face his fears?

Also, in this context what does "bask in the fear of other men" mean?

Comment: I read the two terms slightly differently.  "Facing fear" is simply (if you can apply that term) forcing yourself to stand or move forward while confronted with fear-inducing conditions.  "Conquering fear", on the other hand, implies being able to put the fear out of your mind, so that it does not color your judgment.  (This is all theoretical, of course, and I need to quit because I see my shadow sneaking up on me.)

Comment: "Become fear" in this context is a short way of saying "become the thing that other people are afraid of".  Once you are the thing that others are afraid of, you won't be afraid yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way of facing your fears is to do whatever frightens you, despite your feelings. Ra's Al Gul is telling Bruce Wayne the real way to conquer his fears is to become someone others fear, and revel in making them afraid.